# What/Where are the Naming Rules for Controller actions in a Zend_Application App

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller

I've created a `Zend_Application` using the `zf` tool that's bundled with Zend Framework (1.96, if that matters)

What at the rules for formatting action names and how those action names get translated into into URL paths, and where in the Framework codebase does this happen?

I ask because I tried to create an action like

```
public function createFooAction()
{
}
```

and it wouldn't load with a URL like

```
http://example.com/controller/createFoo
```

BUT, the following did work

```
public function createfooAction()
{
}
http://example.com/controller/createfoo
```

I also know non-alphanumeric characters get treated differently, and I'd like to know the base rules I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CamelCases are translated to dashes, so `createFooAction` would be available as `http://example.com/controller/create-foo`. You can use the [Zend Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) to add/change URL to Action mapping.