# Zend Framework: Using Dashes in Controller Names/URLs

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a URL I would like to look something like http://server/my/action-name

Obviously, I can't have a - in the ControllerName function and an underscore doesn't work. Is this even possible?

Comment: Near dupe with additional information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056910/what-where-are-the-naming-rules-for-controller-actions-in-a-zend-application-app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default

```
http://server/my/action-name
```

will map to

```
MyController::actionNameAction()
```

but you can also [setup arbitrary routes with the Standard Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Answer (score 3):

use camel casing. It works for actions:

```
function actionNameAction()
```