# Zend Framework isn't looking for camel cased actions when using the router

Tags: zend-framework, camelcasing, zend-controller-router

Hi guys im having a spot of bother, hope someone can shed some light on this.

For some strange reason my route comes up saying action does not exist unless i change the camel casing to all lower case for that actions name then it works fine. but then that goes against the naming conventions! and i dont want to make my code sloppy either.

Heres my route:

```
$FrontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$Router = $FrontController->getRouter();
$Router->addRoute("artistsave",
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route
    (
        "artist/save-artist",
        array(
        "controller"=>"artist",
        "action"    =>"saveArtist"
        )
    )
);
```

Now to me this should look in the ArtistController for the action saveArtistsAction, but it doesn't it throws up this error:

> Whoops you encountered the below
>   error. Action "saveartist" does not
>   exist and was not trapped in __call()

So it appears to have removed my camel casing in the router as the a for Artist is now lower case in the error and if i rename my action to match that, it works!

Any idea's why it is not looking for saveArtist?

I realise I could just rename it to save as it is part of the artist object but now I have found this I would like to understand before coming unstuck some other time in the future.

Thanks in advance to any help :)

---

No soon as I sent this I figured it out, but I feel others may fall for the same mistake so best to leave this here and tell the solution!

In the router it is still in URL formatting I was meant to use hyphens not camel casing then the framework works it out. so here is my correction/solution:

```
$Router->addRoute("artistsave",
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route
    (
    "artist/save-artist",
    array(
            "controller"=>"artist",
        "action"    =>"save-artist"
    )
    )
);
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426036/zend-framework-using-dashes-in-controller-names-urls/3426041#3426041

Answer (score -1):

The naming conventions specify that your actions should be named all lowercase up to the word "Action".

So the correct way to name actions is:

saveartistsAction()

somethingthatdoessomethingelseAction()